# Get value from html input to string and transfer to code behind

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I am trying to get value from HTML input but I did not succeed.
i need to transfer it to code behind aspx.cs

I want to transfer input name (card-number) to string.

Code:

```
<link href="Store/creditcardjs-v0.10.13.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="ccjs-card">
  <label class="ccjs-number">
    Card Number
    <input name="card-number" class="ccjs-number" placeholder="•••• •••• •••• ••••">
  </label>

  <label class="ccjs-csc">
    Security Code
    <input name="csc" class="ccjs-csc" placeholder="•••">
  </label>

  <button type="button" class="ccjs-csc-help">?</button>

  <label class="ccjs-name">
    Name on Card
    <input name="name" class="ccjs-name">
  </label>
```

Comment: Are you using JQuery, or just plain JavaScript?

Comment: So submit the form

Comment: i use javascript. please help

Comment: @epascarello if i submit , where the data go?

Comment: To the server side? Do you need it on the clientside or the serverside? Your question is unclear what you are trying to actually do.

Comment: i want transfer it to code behind (aspx.cs)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an id attribute to your input:

```
<input id="card_number" name="card-number" class="ccjs-number" placeholder="•••• •••• •••• ••••">
```

And then get it with plain JavaScript like:

```
var val = document.getElementById("card_number").value;
```

`val` variable holds whatever the input (card-number) has.

Answer (score 0):

Add ID to your label, like this:

```
  <label class="ccjs-number" ID="mylabel">
```

After that get value from that label:

```
<script>
        var a = document.getElementById('myLabel').value = mylabel.innerHTML;
</script
```

A label's value is not posted back; so I think you'd need to use a HiddenField and save the value in that.

Alternatively, you can use a textbox instead of a label.

Comment: variable `a` does not gold the value.. you need ".value".

Comment: @Konstantinos something like that might work acctually?

Comment: the `= mylabel.innerHTML` part is useless in my humble opinion.

Comment: but how i transfer it to code behind? where the script place?